# convert list type to data frame type in R, data.frame and as.data.frame does not wok

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have created A with command data.frame in R, but the data type of A is "list", and I have already tried to convert A to data frame with as.data.frame but it does work, anyone else has same experience? the code are below:

```
A <- data.frame(rep(1,5), row.names=c("A","B","C","D","E"), check.rows = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)
mode(A)
A1 <- as.data.frame(A)
mode(A1)
```

Comment: A `data.frame` is a `list`.  Check `is.data.frame(A)#
[1] TRUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `data.frame` is a `list` with length of each `list` element (`column`) same, the `mode` returns a `list`.  We can use

```
class(A)
#[1] "data.frame"
```

and

```
is.data.frame(A)
#[1] TRUE
```

from @RHertel's commments

```
is.list(A)  
#[1] TRUE
```

or

```
str(A)
#'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ rep(1, 5): num  1 1 1 1 1

dput(A)
```

to confirm that a `data.frame` is also a `list`.

But, `list` also can have equal length and not a `data.frame`

```
l1 <- as.list(1:5)
mode(l1)
#[1] "list"
class(l1)
#[1] "list"
```